# Unable to launch passkey login with security-keys option when implementing passkey on Android

Tags: android, passkey

Does anyone know how can I launch passkey login with security-keys option like the attached image?

I am using following credentials library version.

- "androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.0.0-alpha09"
- "androidx.credentials:credentials:1.0.0-alpha09"

[image]

I tried the change the userVerification or add hints but nothing works.
The request json is from example:

```
{ 
  "allowCredentials": [], 
  "challenge": "DVoOX3w1puCL-hMzfi9uIm9TpIfgF7NG1PA9p23MHjU",
  "hint": ["security-keys"],
  "rpId": "xxx.com",
  "timeout": 180000,
  "userVerification": "discouraged"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force security key options, you would need to specify the required authenticator attachment as `cross-platform`:

```
"authenticatorSelection": {
    "authenticatorAttachment": "cross-platform"
}
```

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#roaming-authenticators

Comment: Hi Ayman,

Thanks for the reply. I had tried adding the authenticatorAttachment to "cross-platform", but it still not show the security-keys options in login prompts on Android.

Comment: what other options have you set in the "authenticatorSelection" section ? I just tried it now and simply switching between "cross-platform" and "platform" authenticatorAttachment changes the options Android provides me. With `cross-platform`, I am getting exactly the same screen as your screenshot, NFC and USB security key. If you have `requireResidentKey` option, set it to false

Comment: hi Ayman, thanks for the reply. I'm using the following the json to do the passkey authentication, but still no security-keys option available for selection.
{
  "allowCredentials": [], 
  "authenticatorSelection": 
    {
      "authenticatorAttachment": "cross-platform", 
      "requireResidentKey": false
    }, 
  "challenge": "FDTD679d3SdXiW8ZbcR4MndGTzdwQNucUWli2OTsye4", 
  "rpId": "xxx.com", 
  "timeout": 180000, 
  "userVerification": "preferred"
}

Comment: BTW, I had filed a ticket to ask the Google support team but they replied this is not supported yet.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/308347011

Comment: Oh, sorry for the assumption I took here, I thought you are already trying it on an Android 14 device !